# Prove the integral of multi-variable rational fraction is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, differential-calculus

I have posted this problem in MSE long ago:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782868/multi-variable-rational-fraction-integral. But it hasn't been solved yet so I post it here. Maybe this problem not so easy. I would like to describe it again.

Consider the polynomial function in $\mathbb{R}^n$: $$f(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|=1}^{m}c_\alpha x^{\alpha}$$
where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)\in \mathbb{N}^n$ is the multi-index with non-negative integers and $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$.

**Problem:** For given $p>0$ such that $|\alpha|p<1$ for any $\alpha$, show that in an open bounded domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\int_{D}\frac{dx}{|f(x)|^p}<+\infty.$$
**Example to understand:**

(1)
$$\int_{(-1,1)^2}\frac{dxdy}{|x^3-xy^3+y^2|^{1/5}}$$

(2) For any $0<\varepsilon<1$
$$\int_{(-1,1)^3}\frac{dxdydz}{|xyz+z^4-y^3x+y^2z|^{(1-\varepsilon)/4}}. $$

**Attempt:** When the case is special I can show this. For example, if $f(x)=x_1+\sum\limits_{~~~~~~|\alpha|=1\\ \text{no $x_1$ appears}}^{m}c_\alpha x^{\alpha}$, then I can take $f(x)=u_1$ and $x_i=u_i$. The Jacobi is $1$ and we can prove it. But in general it doesn't work.

On the other hand, I have tried the special version of *Resolution of Singularities* (see, e.g. page 147 in Atiyah's https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/cpa.3160230202). But this thoery only makes $f$ become monomial locally with abstract power $\beta_i$ ($g$ is the blow-down map):
$$f\circ g(u)=c(u)u_1^{\beta_1}\cdots u_n^{\beta_n}.$$
Since the power $\beta_i$'s are abstract, the condition $|\alpha|p<1$ doesn't work.

I also tried to apply some theorem in real analysis. For example:

> Suppose $f\geq 0$ and is finite almost everywhere. Let $E_k=\{x:f(x)>2^k\}$, then $f$ is integrable if and only if $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}2^km(E_k)<\infty. $$
> One can find this proposition (as an exercise) in Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis.

Back to this problem. $E_k=\{x:\frac{1}{|f(x)|^p}>2^k\}=\{x:|f(x)|<2^{-\frac{k}{p}}\}$. But I'm stuck in estimating the Lebesgue measure of $E_k$. Is there any way of reference to finish it?

Or you can give some new ways to show this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm questioner. Now I have found a reference:

[Volume estimates of sublevel sets of real polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04544.pdf)

Theorem 4.1 in it can solve this proplem.

This paper has been published at
[Annales Polonici Mathematici](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/annales-polonici-mathematici/all/121/2/112545/volume-estimates-of-sublevel-sets-of-real-polynomials)